# How to get graphs data from coinmarketcap.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bitcoin

I want to fetch the graph details from coinmarketcap.com such as 30 days, 60 days, 90 days. Can anyone know how to fetch the graph data to load into my application.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should ask that here. https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=199685.0 As far as I know, they DO NOT have an api!